# recyclerview inside horizontalscrollview

Tags: android

how can i put vertical recyclerview inside horizontalScrollview ?

when adapter binds data at viewholder, item's left margin is increase.

(ex : leftMargin = position * 100)

but doesn't work horizontalScrollview.
help me ~~
sorry for my bad english.
[image]

my activity layout  .xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and list_item .xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bullet" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: why do you put the recycleView inside horrizontalScroll? you can achieve another this by using RecycleView and make it horizoltal.

Comment: thanks i try it.
i think your solution needs two adapter. can i get more easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is a list of items that scroll horizontally, use `LinearLayoutManager` with your `RecyclerView`.

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(
  this,
  LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
  false
);
```

Comment: thanks, but i want recyclerview's parent view has horizontal scroll.

Comment: What is exactly your use case? Maybe there's a better option

Comment: my vertical recyclerview's items have left margin. their left margin values are increase by position . like this ->  list's index * 100 .
so first item's margin 0, and second item's margin 100 ... so items right side not visible. i want to horizontal scroll  for show their right side. ( look my picture) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must set width for recyclerview => it's done.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).